# python emailing using BCC by default instead of To

Tags: python, smtp

I'm trying to create a simple python program to send an email. Here are the relevant lines of code. I want this to send an email using the To field. When I run the program, and check the test email account, it seems that the program is sending it via BCC.

Here are the relevant lines of code.

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server) 
smtp.sendmail(send_from,["testaddress@testdomain.com"],"hello")
```

Is there a setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail:

> Note The from_addr and to_addrs parameters are used to construct the message envelope used by the transport agents. The SMTP does not modify the message headers in any way.

So this means that you construct the "To:" headers that recipients will see in the message body, but choose actual recipients the message will go to in the `to_addrs` parameter to `sendmail`.  For example:

```
message='To: {}\r\nSubject: {}\r\n\r\n{}'.format('visible@example.com', subject, body)

smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
smtp.sendmail(send_from, ['visible@example.com', 'invisible@example.com'], message)
smtp.quit()
```

and `invisible@example.com` will be BCC'd.